# html entity decode does not remove html elements like <b>

Tags: php, html

I have this string that contains `html`, `p` ,`div`, `b`

```
$string = "this is a <b> test </b>";

echo html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

When I echo it on my page it is shown like this:

```
this is a <b> test </b>
```

What should I do to make it work properly?

Desired result :

this is a  **test**

Comment: echo $string; if you want test to be bold you do not need to use html_entity_decode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`htmlspecialchars_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php).

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($string);
```